# XmlSerializer invokes InvalidOperationException when parsing custom Element

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xmlserializer, invalidoperationexception

I have a problem while Parsing a custom element with the XmlSerializer. My custom element looks like this (i removed all properties, it still does not work):

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace MvvmControlChange.Content.Elements
{
    public class Test_Element : TextBox
    {
        public Test_Element()
        { }
    }
}
```

Now this line of my parser invokes a InvalidOperationException for Test_Element:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test_Element));
```

The InnerExcetion tells me "There was an error reflecting property 'InputBindings'. Can someone help me?

Comment: Is there an InnerException as well?

Comment: Where is the sense in serializing a TextBox control? If you'd tell us what you are trying to achieve here, we might provide an adequate solution.

Comment: Its not easy to explain, its a rather cpmplex program where i need custom elements that extend classes like textbox or shape. @LasseV.Karlsen, the InnerExcetion tells me "There was an error reflecting property 'InputBindings'.